# Using Axios in a Vue Component...promise comes after the error

Tags: elasticsearch, vue.js, axios

I'm querying an elasticsearch database using axios within a vue component. When axios runs a get request, it immediately returns `Error: Request failed with status code 400`. But after checking the the console, I see that the `get` request was successful and the functions within the promises ran (albeit after the error was returned).

I'm using the data retrieved from the `get` request to fill out the component's template, but I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`. What I understand is that the data eventually does show up (at least in the console) but it's too late to render onto the screen.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

```
<template>
  <div style="position: fixed; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9); top: 2.5%; left: 2.5%; width: 95%; height: 95%; z-index: 100">
    <div style="position:absolute; background-color: #9BBB58; width: 100%; height:3%">
      <button style='float:right;' @click="$emit('close-viz')">x</button>
    </div>
    <div v-bind:style="{position: 'absolute',  height: "100%", width: "100%", 'overflow-y': 'scroll'}" >
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Publications</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for='paper in pubdata.data.hits.hits'>
          {{console.log(paper)}}
          <a v-bind:href="paper._source.link">
            <h3 v-if="paper._souce.title">{{paper._source.title}}</h3>
          </a>
          <p v-if="paper._source.abstract">
            {{paper._source.abstract}}
          </p>
          <p>
            <button @click="queryItem('firm', paper._source.firm)">{{paper._source.firm}}</button> was awarded ${{paper._source.amount}} in {{paper._source.year}}
          </p>
          <p>
            The PI is <button @click="queryItem('PIName', paper._source.PIName)">{{paper._source.PIName}}</button> and the the business contact is <button @click="queryItem('BusName', paper._source.BusName)">{{paper._source.BusName}}</button>
          </p>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  props: ["field", "query"],
  data() {
    return {
      pubData: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    const fullQuery = this.queryItem(this.field, this.query)
    this.runQuery(fullQuery)
  },
  methods: {
    queryItem: function(field, query) {
      const fullQuery = JSON.parse(`{
            "size": 100,
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "${field}": "${query}"
              }
            }
          }`)

      this.runQuery(fullQuery)
    },
    runQuery: function(query) {
      axios.get("http://localhost:9200/sbir/_search", {
        params: {
          source: query,
          source_content_type: 'application/json'
        }
      }).
      then(res => {
        console.log('inside pubinfo')
        this.pubData = res;
        console.log(this.pubData)
      }).
      catch(function(error) {
        console.log('BELOW IS AN ERROR')
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `JSON.parse(template literal)`?  I think you can leverage [Object literal computed property keys](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/#computed-property-keys).  That doesn't answer your question, but it is something to note.

Comment: And can you show the HTML that uses the data?

Comment: I just updated the question to include the template of the component. The reason I use the JSON.Parse is because I want to use the same query format, but change the specifics like which field gets queried and what the field should match. I figured javascripts string template would be the best way to achieve this. This component is created from a parent component with a similar template.

Comment: also, I've never heard of object literal computed property keys. I'm reading into it now

Comment: Casing? `<tr v-for='paper in pubdata.data.hits.hits'>` is all lowercase while the var itself is camelized, i.e. `pubData`.

Comment: This is really embarrassing... after you pointed that one typo out I found another one....

Comment: thanks @i-- in the end the main issues were the typo.